# Allow my users to remove root-owned directories within their HOME

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

My users are on Ubuntu running Docker and mounting directories in their sessions. The problem is that any non-existing directory or file mounted with Docker is owned by root.

**I would like to allow my users to remove any root-owned file or directory under their `$HOME` directory with an `/etc/sudoers` directive.** Something like :

```sh
# /!\ This is not working
%MyUsers ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/rm $HOME/*
```

- Is it possible within `/etc/sudoers` ?
- What options do I have ?

Thanks for your help.

*Using Docker-rootless mode is not an option for us.*

Answer (score 2):

If they're running docker as root, and they can control the daemon, they're already root.

Trying to grant them limited `sudo` permissions is pointless and you're better off granting them full root access to their machines.

In addition to which, it is nearly impossible without a wrapper to grant them permission to execute `rm $HOME/*` as root securely. I'd just have to `ln -s / $HOME/root` and I could delete anything.

Comment: Additionally, the users only need to run a container with a shell to remove the directory.